Tensorflow pipeline with image as byte[]>
C# + Microsoft.ML project to run TensorFlow Image Classification model. Microsoft.ML provides two methods to load images into TensorFlow pipeline - LoadImages and LoadRawImageBytes, but both includes folder where files are located. However, I store files in DB and have List of InMemoryImageData
public class InMemoryImageData {
    [LoadColumn(0)]
    public byte[] Image;
    [LoadColumn(1)]
    public string Label;
}

How I can load it to pipeline?
Microsoft provided an example to work with in-memory-images, but only to use them for predict, not for model training
